# How to use the last method in laravel

Tags: laravel

I would like to use the last method the way it is possible to use the first method in Laravel with `App\Model::first`

I can't get the equivalent eloquent of last.

Comment: if you have a specific order in mind you can reverse it (e.g.if doing `orderBy('id')` you can do `orderBy('id', 'desc')` but if not you need to know the exact total number of results which requires another query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`last()`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-last) is a method of the [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections) class. If you want to execute it over a model or in an instance of the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries), you might do it like this:

```
$lastRecord = Model::latest()->first();
```